# How to change css property (like cursor:wait, or background) before AND after ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cursor, wait

I'm having problems with this code, I'm trying to show a red background while a function is working, and then (only then) I'm changing the background to green.

When the following alert is not commented, I can see the red background for a while and then the green (that's what I want).

But when I comment that alert, seems like the red background is never set and once processData has finished, the background is set to green, correctly.

Can somebody solve this mystery for me? thanks!

```
function beforeProcess(params){
    $('#result').css('background','red');
    alert('now i start waiting, while background is red');
    $.when(processData(params)).done(
        $('#result').css('background','green')
    );
}


function process(params){
     //This function takes some time, and it makes (indirectly) some synchronous ajax calls (async:false)
}
```

Comment: I believe you have a syntax error and needs to wrap done in a function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is only updated after the function finishes execution. This can be accomplished using a setTimeout
http://jsfiddle.net/YEVHv/4/

```
$('#result').css('background', 'red');
//alert('now i start waiting, while background is red');
setTimeout(function () {
    $.when(process("")).done(
    $('#result').css('background', 'green'));
}, 0);


function process(params) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

My guessing is that your function "process" returns quickly... remember that every function call in JS is performed async. If you want to show progress or display some state (red color) while processing, you must be sure that the function process returns after all sub-functions finish. Right now, I can only think about using standard callbacks.

$.when is useful when it used with deferred objects. If the function you use is not a deferred object, the "done" is executed immediately. Please, take a look at the following extract from "http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/" : "If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately."

Hope this helps